# Batch Scripting, Unzip / move files to a folder / output listing to file

Tags: batch-file

I currently have a problem im trying to figure out how to get started using notepad++ creating a batch script.

The problem is;

Write a batch file to unzip and move all files that contain “HQ” to a folder called HQsource .  Output the listing of the directory to a file.

I have the zipped file that came with it, and within does contain some generic files some with HQ in its name.

Any help and or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

The comment doesnt mention really how to extract all files with HQ within the zip, not sure how much that could help.

Comment: What unzip tool are you going to use?

Comment: Well the folder is compressed via the windows compressed folder. Do I need an unzip tool/program since you can use that as it is to extract the files within.

Comment: @BryceConley What you are talking about? A `*.zip` archive file containing 0 to n files with `HQ` in file name or a folder on an NTFS drive with compression attribute set so that NTFS compresses the files on write and decompress them on read automatically?